My rest api (using Express.js) in a container gets denied acces to my mariadb. How do I make my api able to connect to my mariadb?
I want to run a rest api using Express.js that I can use to handle the api calls from my webapp so that I can get data from my database. This is because I am using a flutter application and that cannot make the calls straight to the database and this was also the more secure option (gave me more control).
So I first created the rest api that can connect to the database and with different routes can make different calls towards the database. Next I made sure it runs on my pc and it did. Next thing I put it in a container and made sure it was able to run in the container on my pc and it did. Finally I pushed my image on Docker hub and pulled it on my server and tried to run it there. Then came this error that I can't fix and where I am stuck at:
  sqlMessage: "Access denied for user '<my_username>'@'<my_ip>' (using password: YES)"

Now some more context for my problem:

The MariaDB is running in a container with this image: alpine-mariadb
The rest api is running in a container on a different server and has a NodeJs Image. This container does everything else except connecting to the MariaDB
The server I am trying to run the api on is a machine that runs Linux with Ubuntu.

So I do not know why my api is denied access to use the database. Here are the things I have tried to overcome this problem:

Enabling root access with password to my mariadb and using those credentials on my api but that still got denied.
Testing all the environment variables and made sure the api is using the correct credentials to connect to the database.
On my database edited the my.cnf file to make sure it accepted traffic from every ip address.
Testing the api container on my own pc to make sure its able to run and it runs fine there.
Making sure my servers are not being blocked by a firewall.

For some more context this is my dockerfile:
ARG NODE_VERSION=18.5.0

FROM node:${NODE_VERSION}-alpine

ENV NODE_ENV production

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN --mount=type=bind,source=package.json,target=package.json \
    --mount=type=bind,source=package-lock.json,target=package-lock.json \
     --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.npm \
     npm ci 

USER node

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["node", "app.js"]

And this is my compose.yaml file:
services:
  server:
    build:
      context: .
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: production
    env_file:
      - path: .env
        required: true
    ports:
      - 3000:3000

I really do not know what to do now. If anybody had this problem before some help would really be appreciated!
Update
I now have the database also in a container on the same server as the api. Still have the same issue but that is what has changed.

The issue is because your permissions on mysql is restricted to localhost or a specific ip. You need to run the command create user blah@%  on your database to allow access from remote hosts. You may also need to set your server binding. You may also want to run your docker container using network in bridge mode.

I will look into the “acces from remote host” but the other stuff I already had implemented

I tried everything from that list and I still get the same error

If you ensured the firewall is correct then the issue is almost certainty that you do not have your permissions incorrect on your mariadb instance. See https://mariadb.com/kb/en/configuring-mariadb-for-remote-client-access/
